# Angular Material Tabs and Bottom Sheet Vertical Issue

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm running an AngularJS (angular version 1.4.3) application and I'm trying to use two Angular Material elements on the same page:  [Tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.tabs) and the [Bottom Sheet](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.bottomSheet).

Both work as expected when I use them in isolation.  However, when I put both elements on the page at the same time, the bottom sheet's vertical position gets messed up with the dynamic height of the tabs, as shown in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b10od50j/3/) (switch to tab "Two" and hit the "Help!" button to see the problem).  Both were installed with bower and came with the packaged .css files.

Here is my controller and view:

```
angular.module('tabsDemo2', ['ngMaterial']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $mdBottomSheet) {
  $scope.showListBottomSheet = function($event) {
        $scope.alert = '';
        $mdBottomSheet.show({
          templateUrl: 'help-panel.html',
          targetEvent: $event
        }).then(function(clickedItem) {
          $scope.alert = clickedItem.name + ' clicked!';
        });
      };  
});
```

and

```
<body ng-app="tabsDemo2">
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <md-content class="md-padding">
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
      <md-tab label="one">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi.</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="two">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis ante augue. Phasellus volutpat neque ac dui mattis vulputate. Etiam consequat aliquam cursus. In sodales pretium ultrices. Maecenas lectus est, sollicitudin consectetur felis nec, feugiat ultricies mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam placerat, tortor in ultrices porttitor, orci enim rutrum enim, vel tempor sapien arcu a tellus. Vivamus convallis sodales ante varius gravida. Curabitur a purus vel augue ultrices ultricies id a nisl. Nullam malesuada consequat diam, a facilisis tortor volutpat et. Sed urna dolor, aliquet vitae posuere vulputate, euismod ac lorem. Sed felis risus, pulvinar at interdum quis, vehicula sed odio. Phasellus in enim venenatis, iaculis tortor eu, bibendum ante. Donec ac tellus dictum neque volutpat blandit. Praesent efficitur faucibus risus, ac auctor purus porttitor vitae. Phasellus ornare dui nec orci posuere, nec luctus mauris semper.</p>
          <p>Morbi viverra, ante vel aliquet tincidunt, leo dolor pharetra quam, at semper massa orci nec magna. Donec posuere nec sapien sed laoreet. Etiam cursus nunc in condimentum facilisis. Etiam in tempor tortor. Vivamus faucibus egestas enim, at convallis diam pulvinar vel. Cras ac orci eget nisi maximus cursus. Nunc urna libero, viverra sit amet nisl at, hendrerit tempor turpis. Maecenas facilisis convallis mi vel tempor. Nullam vitae nunc leo. Cras sed nisl consectetur, rhoncus sapien sit amet, tempus sapien.</p>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="three">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1>
          <p>Integer turpis erat, porttitor vitae mi faucibus, laoreet interdum tellus. Curabitur posuere molestie dictum. Morbi eget congue risus, quis rhoncus quam. Suspendisse vitae hendrerit erat, at posuere mi. Cras eu fermentum nunc. Sed id ante eu orci commodo volutpat non ac est. Praesent ligula diam, congue eu enim scelerisque, finibus commodo lectus.</p>
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>

<div class="">
    <div class="bottom-sheet-demo inset" layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center">
    <md-button flex="30" class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showListBottomSheet($event)">Help!</md-button>
</div>

</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="help-panel.html"><md-bottom-sheet class="md-list md-has-header">
  <md-subheader>Comment Actions</md-subheader>
  This is where help panel content goes.
    </md-bottom-sheet>
</script>

</body>
```

I have a suspicion it has something to do with how the Tabs deal with scrolling combined with how the Bottom Sheet deals with its position.  I found [this issue](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1426) on the Angular Material github, but the fixes there don't seem to help when both Tabs and a Bottom Sheet are present.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe try using flex row to separate them?

Comment: No dice on the flex div to separate them.  (I added `<div style="display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; flex-direction:row"></div>` and the behavior doesn't change)

Comment: This may actually be a problem with the way the bottom sheet handles heights when the page scrolls.  I've duplicated the behavior with other scrolling pages that don't include the angular material tabs.

Comment: Definitely post it in their Github!  I played with it for a bit and see what you mean.